# the popup appears on page load as well. I cant figure out the error

Tags: javascript, html, css

However the popup appears onload.
I only need it onclick.

the code :

```
#pop {
    height: 280 px;
    width: 470 px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50 % ;
    right: 50 % ;
    border: 2 px solid;
    padding: 10 px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border - radius: 9 px;
}
#close {
    right: 5;
    top: 5;
    float: right;
}
```

```
<a href="">
    <img class="h" src="nfl.jpg" height="152" width="" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block';">
</a>
<div id="pop"> TEXT GOES HERE.
    <button id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('pop') .style.display='none'">X</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not enough code - can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Give `display:none` in css to `#pop`. So that it will not display on load.

Comment: it blocks the popup on page load but it also blocks onclick. @Manwal

Comment: It should not happened css can't block working of JS in this case. It should work with it. You can try another solution type to add on body onload `<body onload="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block';">`

Comment: does'nt work @Manwal

Answer (score 0):

Set display none in the CSS and you need to cancel the click action of the link.

```css
#pop {
    display: none;
    height: 280 px;
    width: 470 px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50 % ;
    right: 50 % ;
    border: 2 px solid;
    padding: 10 px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border - radius: 9 px;
}
#close {
    right: 5;
    top: 5;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
    <img class="h" src="nfl.jpg" height="152" width="" onclick="document.getElementById('pop').style.display='block'; return false;">
</a>
<div id="pop"> TEXT GOES HERE.
    <button id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('pop') .style.display='none'">X</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly find in the demo above. Did you add the `return false` to the onclick?

Comment: Yes i did but no avail @epascarello

Comment: There has to be another issue since this basic code above is working. what is different from the code you gave and the actual page?